# how to handle error when there is no coordinate to show in arraylist?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, maps

I need your help, how to handle an error in Get Coordinate button when there is no coordinate to show in array list?

This is my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder mAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Hotel.this);

view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_background, null);
ImageView Content_img = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
TextView Content_txt1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

Content_img.setImageResource(item_detail.get(position).getImageNumber());
Content_txt1.setText(item_detail.get(position).getName());

mAlert.setTitle(item_detail.get(position).getName()).
setView(view).
setPositiveButton("Get Coordinate", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{

     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
     {
           dialog.dismiss();
           Intent intent = new Intent(Hotel.this, MapsActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("lon", item_detail.get(position).lon);
           intent.putExtra("lat", item_detail.get(position).lat);
           Hotel.this.startActivity(intent);
     }

}).create().show();
```

this is my arraylist, one of the arrays has coordinates and another one does not :

```
private ArrayList<ItemDetail> GetSearchResult() 
{
  ArrayList<ItemDetail> result = new ArrayList<ItemDetail>();

  ItemDetail item_detail = new ItemDetail();
  item_detail.setName("Taman Sari");
  item_detail.setImageNumber(images[0]);
  item_detail.ALoc(-6.917222222, 106.9758333);
  result.add(item_detail);

  item_detail = new ItemDetail();
  item_detail.setName("Taman Tirta");
  item_detail.setImageNumber(images[1]);
  result.add(item_detail);


  return result;
}
```

Comment: This should be part of your use cases that how you will handle exceptional conditions. 
Suggestion: In `ItemDetail` you should supply default value to Aloc()'s parameter, So, if no input is provided then default values will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get a `lon` and `lat` at first and check them for `null`, for instance. If they are `null`, you can show `Toast` with error.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Hotel.this, MapsActivity.class);
        Object lan = item_detail.get(position).lon;
        Object lat = item_detail.get(position).lat;
        if (lan == null || lat == null){
            //show toast
        } else {
            intent.putExtra("lon", lon);
            intent.putExtra("lat", lat);
            Hotel.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two possibilities: ensure every `ItemDetail` has parameters set, so that you can rely on this by displaying every `ItemDetail` or do error handling by not showing anything and an error message or something likely.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:
    Set default values for the parameter, this way you need not to check for `null` when getting the values from the object. If new values are not supplied then old values will be used.

```
class ItemDetail{

type param1 = value1; // some default value say 21
type param2 = value2; // some default value say 43
public void ALoc(type param1, type param2){

}

}
```

Solution 2:

```
 onclick(onclick-param){

  type value = item_detail.get(position).lon;
  if(value == null){
     // no value supplied.
   }else{
    // value supplied
   }
}
```